# Yocto using .bbappend file to override writing of default init scripts for initramfs

Tags: init, yocto, bitbake, openembedded

I am trying to write a `.bbappend` file that will append to the `initramfs-live-boot_1.0.bb` which has a statement inside the `do_install()` that writes the contents of `init-live.sh`, a shell script that manages the boot procedure, to `init`, an initialisation script that runs upon boot. The purpose of my `.bbappend` file is to reference a modified version of the startup script to be copied in place of the original without changing the base `openembedded-core` and/or `poky` environments. The `.bbappend` file and my version of the script is therefore placed in my project directory with the rest of my own recipes to be built.

My `initramfs-live-boot_1.0.bbappend` looks like this:

```
SUMMARY = "Replacement recipe"
FILESEXTRAPATH_prepend := "${THISDIR}/files:"
SRC_URI += "file://init.sh"

do_install_append() {
        install -m 0755 ${WORKDIR}/init.sh ${D}/init
}
```

I have a folder `files` in the same directory as the `.bbappend` file that contains the `init.sh` script it should be reading from.

The problem is when I try to build the image, it spits out this error:

```
WARNING: Failed to fetch URL file://init.sh, attempting MIRRORS if available
```

and then attempts to search through the `poky` directory for the missing files rather than in my project directory.

Have I written my `.bbappend` file wrong? How would I go about editing the `initramfs` scripts using the `.bbappend` file?

Answer (score 22, accepted):

`FILESEXTRAPATH_prepend := "${THISDIR}/files:"` should be `FILESEXTRAPATHS_prepend := "${THISDIR}/files:"`. Note the last S in `FILESEXTRAPATHS`.

That should make it work for you.

Another improvement would be to rename you file file from `init.sh` to `init-live.sh`. I.e. use the same name as the file in the original `initramfs-live-boot`recipe. That would allow you to remove your `do_install_append()`-function as well as `SRC_URI += "file://init.sh"` from the bbappend. The recipe itself would handle those for you. Thus, the only line you'd actually need is the `FILESEXTRAPATHS_prepend := "${THISDIR}/files:"`.

Comment: So to clarify, all I need in my `.bbappend` is `FILESEXTRAPATHS_prepend := "${THISDIR}/files:"` ?

Comment: Yes, assuming you name the file `init-live.sh`, just as the original file.

Comment: Awesome! Thanks for your answer, just tried it out and it hasn't thrown the error.